# How do Radical Pairs Result in Magnetoreception?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, biology

*An Immense World* by Ed Yong is a fantastic book on sensory biology and has a great section on magnetoreception. Although it is confirmed with behavioral studies that many species of birds have magnetoreception, we don't know how it is done. One explanation relies heavily on quantum physics:

> When light hits the two partner molecules, one donates an electron to
> the other, leaving both of them with an unpaired electron. Molecules
> with unpaired electrons are called radicals: hence, the radical pair.
> Electrons have a property called spin, whose exact nature we can leave
> to the quantum physicists. What matters to biologists is that spin can
> either be up or down; the radical pair can either have the same spins
> or opposite ones; they flip between these two states several million
> times a second; and **the magnetic field can change the frequency of
> these flips.** So depending on the magnetic field, the two molecules end
> up in one state or another, which in turn affects how chemically
> reactive they are.

This is how I understand that passage:
1: A radical pair forms by an electron moving from one molecule to another.
2: These two molecules can be in one of 4 states; both up, both down, opposite state with donator up, or opposite states with donator down.
3: The radical pair is in one of those states at a time, but switch which state they are currently in. The rate this switching happens is dependent on the local magnetic field.
4: The chemical properties of the radical pair are dependent on how long it spends in each state.

What I am confused by is step 3. At first I thought the radical pair is actually quantum entangled and Yong was simplifying for the book, but apparently [quantum entanglement is not required](https://phys.org/news/2010-06-physicists-role-quantum-entanglement-magnetic.html) for magnetoreception. It seems that even if we understand these states classically, without superpositions, magnetoreception can still result. That just leaves the question of how the local magnetic field influences changes in the radical pair states. I could not find a explanation for this, so if anyone knows I would greatly appreciate the help.